# web api POST returns 500 error with AllowAnonymous Requests

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, dotnetnuke

I have a **DNN 9.2** website set up on a local server.  I use a HttpPOST to send JSON to the web.api.  This was working last week and has now stopped working when I am attempting to upgrade from **Angular 4.1 to 4.3**.

When I try to access the api endpoint from within my app or a postman call I get a 500 error and no message.

Here is my Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("postPost")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ApiResult UpsertPost([FromBody]Post post)
{
  try
  {
    DO STUFF HERE
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    CATCH ERROR
  }
}
```

What is funny here is that this was working and All I did was change to use the new httpClient from Angular 4.3. I know the api endpoint is taking requests.

### What I tried:

1. I tried to take angular out of the loop by using postman calls. However, I also can not use the postman calls I had set up as tests and I get the same error.
2. I tried changing the security attribute from **[AllowAnonymous]** to ** a DNN built in security attribute: [DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)]** but I get the following error instead of a 500 error:

> Authorization has been denied for this request.

3. The same error is given as above if I change the security attribute to [DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.View)]
4. I made sure the POST action was supported in my web.config file:

   add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"

I know the api endpoints are getting hit because if I use GET instead of POST I can hit all my breakpoints in the web.pai code.  As well as the given "Authorization has been denied for this request" is given from the api service.

### QUESTION

Can someone help me figure out why my DNN api's with post are not accepting requests?

Comment: Angular is a front-end framework, it has nothing to do with your API on the back-end. Do you have version control to track other changes?

Comment: @wannadream Thanks for the feedback.  I have reviewed the version control and can not seem to find the issue.  I understand that angular is a front-end framework, but like most front-end frameworks, they need to generate authorization tokens etc that do affect the responses from backend APIs, and it was after upgrading angular that the problem appeared, I had not changed the server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so no surprise that it was my fault.  I had moved the authorization process for the http requests to the new httpClient interceptors.  I had an error in the interceptor function that was creating a poorly formed request.  Once I fixed the interceptor the API requests work properly now.

Hope this might help someone

Answer (score 1):

I know that you got an answer by yourself, but can be usefull these links:

You can find a "scafolding angular project" here: [DNN-Angular-6-7-CLI](https://github.com/OPSI-srl/DNN-Angular-6-7-CLI)

And DNN module where to deploy your project: SPA DNN9: [DNN-9.x-SPA-and-Angular-6-7](https://github.com/OPSI-srl/DNN-9.x-SPA-and-Angular-6-7)

ASCX for all DNN: [DNN-7.x-8.x-9.x-and-Angular-6-7](https://github.com/OPSI-srl/DNN-7.x-8.x-9.x-and-Angular-6-7)

all works with dnn webapi and security.

I used these projects with my customers.

Matteo

Comment: thanks Matteo, looks like a great project, I will give it a try